# API, .factory, .controller error

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, api, rest

I try to fetch data from a [json file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/forecast-api/forecast.json).
This is the JS code:

```
var app = angular.module('ForecastApp', []);
console.log('in app');

//fetches weather data from service
  var res ="";
app.factory('forecast', ['$http', function($http) {

$http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/forecast-api/forecast.json')
          .success(function(data) { console.log(data); res = data; })
          .error(function(err) { console.log(err); res = err;});
          return res;
}]);

//Save weather data into $scope.fiveDay
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'forecast', function($scope, forecast) {
      $scope.fiveDay = res;
      console.log('in controller');
    }]);
```

Then i run in the main HTML file:

```
<body ng-app="ForecastApp">
    <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
      ...
            <h1>{{ fiveDay.city_name }}</h1>
...
```

`fiveDay.city_name` doesn't return anything, it just shows blank. `fiveDay` should have the value of `res`, which is an object, right? I don't understand why `fiveDay.city_name` isn't New York.

Comment: try to create MainController's reference and then display city_name. Like `ng-controller="MainController as main"` and then `{{main.fiveDay.city_name}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have provided a simple Solution, just using $http Service in the controller

```js
var app = angular.module('ForecastApp', []);
console.log('in app');


//Save weather data into $scope.fiveDay
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/forecast-api/forecast.json')
          .success(function(data) { console.log(data); $scope.fiveDay = data; })
          .error(function(err) { console.log(err);});
         
      console.log('in controller');
    }]);
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.6" data-semver="1.4.6" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="ForecastApp">
    <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
      ...
            <h1>{{ fiveDay.city_name }}</h1>
            </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

see plunker here [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NrbdznGmFJGfcQyqNdBM?p=preview)

Comment: It worked thanks! Now it shows "New York". Can you tell me what I wasn't doing right?

Comment: If you can't see it, I guess you not familiar with async processing and promises. The short answer to your question is: your forecast service returns res before $http.get is resolved. I would recommend you to read more about async processing in javascript because it is of great importance for web programming.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use a custom service this is a way to do it.

```
app.factory('forecastService', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/forecast-api/forecast.json');
}]);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'forecastService', function($scope, forecastService) {
  forecastService.then(function(success) { $scope.fiveDay = success.data});
}]);
```

Your service here returns a promise where you can use the `.then` method on.
This way the controller don't need to know any thing about the URL.

You don't want any global variables hanging around in your scripts when using angular. This is exactly why angular services / factories. They provide a way to share data between multiple controllers and other services.

Here is a [plunker showing the action](http://plnkr.co/edit/lJfIw2SotOMFNCAhRSt5?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for the solution and tip.